# menu_main cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android

I have checked my menu folder and it has a menu_main.xml. But the menu_main in activity cannot be resolved.

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your app your menu is in the "menu" folder, not just in your resources.

You need to change the line of code to reference the menu folder of your resources, so it should be.

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
```